# FastTrack Duo Line Out with monitors as windows default sound device

Tags: audio-interfaces, playback, avid, windows-10

I have a FastTrack Duo on Windows10 with the latest drivers etc. I have a pair of monitors connected on the 2 x Line Out 1/4" connections at the rear. It works fine for monitoring output with Cubase and of course through the headphones.

I have also set the FastTrack Duo as my default Windows10 device for system sounds etc., for when I am not using Cubase / Music Maker / Sequel etc.

As the Windows10 default Playback device I can use the headphone monitor but I want to use the stereo monitors instead. However I have not been able to get sound out through the monitors as the default Windows10 device.

I cannot find where I can configure this in windows or in the device driver.

Can anyone tell me is this possible? How?

Comment: Oops, just saw this in an mAudio manual: "These outputs are disabled when headphones are connected to the Headphone Output on the front panel". I will have to try this without the 1/4" to 1/8th" adaptor left in the headphone socket!

Comment: Can you add that as an answer if it does sort the problem - that will help future visitors with the same issue. Thanks

Comment: Sure Rory, will do. I am a long time user of StackOverflow and know the benefits of Answers. I plan to look at it tonighht

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well it turns out that I had something plugged into the headphones socket which gates the outputs to the monitors.
It works!